# Amazon EC2 Windows Server - Cannot Extend C Drive After Extending EBS Volume

Tags: windows, amazon-ec2, windows-server-2016, amazon-ebs

I have an EC2 instance running Windows Server 2016 that contains 3 disks (C, D, E) stored one 1 EBS volume.

I have just extended the volume (from 300GB to 400GB) and am now trying to resize the disks within Windows.
In the disk management utility, I only get the "Extend Volume..." option on Disk E - Disks C and D do not give me the option.

Is there any way to extend the C and D disks to split the additional 100GB between them?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hi this is bit tricky windows is allowed to increase the partition size when the unallocated partition size is adjacent to the about to increase partition eg: c drive has an adjacent unallocated partition

If you are using inbuilt windows disk manager you cannot achieve this because you need to have your D drive.

You have to use a partitioning tool like DiskGenius 
EaseUS partition manager etc.